# Access - Number fields all defaulting to zero

Tags: ms-access

For some reason my number fields are all defaulting to 0 when I first create them. I can change the default while in the process of creating the field, but would rather that it not be automatically defaulted to that. I must have changed an overall default somewhere, but can't track it down. When I go to Options | Object Designers, I don't see anything that would default the values in a numbers field. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have searched for an answer on this, but can't figure out how to word the search because I am looking for a default for the default.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit and add some information what you would expect your numbers to default to and how do you think it could work? You'd have more chance someone could help you.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "overall default" for this. MS Access defaults all number field that you add to a table to zero. If you want to use another default, you'll have to change it while creating the number field.

Comment: What version of Access? My Access 2010 (and as far as I know 2013 and 2016 as well) default to `null`, not `zero`.

Comment: I am using Access 2016. The number fields on my tables were all defaulting to NULL (as I would expect them to) until recently. I am not sure what changed. When I look at my older fields the numbers fields all look blank (NULL), except the later ones that are showing 0, with the default also showing 0.